# Worst case running time of constructing a BST?

Tags: runtime, binary-search-tree

Could someone explain to me how the Worst case running time of constructing a BST is n^2? I asked my professor and the only feedback i received is

"Because the tree is linear to the size of the input. The cost is 1+2+3+4+...+(n-1)."

Can someone explain this in a different way? Her explanation makes me think its O(n)....

Answer (score 0):

I think the worst case happens when the input is already sorted:
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H.
That's why you might want to randomly permute the input sequence if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The worst-case running time is proportional to the square of the input because the BST is unbalanced. An ubalanced BST can exhibit a degenerate structure: in the worst case, a singly linked list.   Constructing this list will require that each insertion marches down the full length of the growing list to get to the leaf node to add a new leaf.

For instance, try running the algorithm on data which is precisely in the reverse order, so that each new node must become the new leftmost node of the tree.

A BST (even a balanced one!) can be constructed in linear time only if the input data is already sorted. Moreover, this is done using a special algorithm which takes advantage of the order; not by performing N insertions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the 1+2+3+4+...+(n-1) insertion steps are clear, (for a reversed ordered list).

You should get comfortable with the idea that this number of steps is quadratic.  Think about running the algorithm twice and count the number of steps:

[1+2+3+4+...+(n-1)] + [1+2+3+4+...+(n-1)] = [1+2+3+4+...+(n-1)] + [(n-1) + ... + 4+3+2+1] = n+n+...n = n^2

Therefore, one run take 0.5*n^2 steps.